# Ember: Bubble action from component to application controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have a component in ember, which needs to send an action (with one parameter) to the application controller. No matter where this component is rendered, it needs to call the exact same action, on application controller.

**application-controller**

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    addAlert: function(message) {
      this.set('message', message);
    },
    removeAlert: function(message) {
      this.set('message', message);
    }
  }
});
```

How do I handle this? From start, to end.

Comment: Did you check the guide here: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/components/sending-actions-from-components-to-your-application/ ?

Comment: Any reason why you aren't catching it on the application route?

Comment: @Kitler I am modifying the property on controller, so I want the action to be there

Comment: Actions don't bubble up through controllers, they do bubble up through routes, you can catch it on the application route and set the controller property from there.

Comment: @Kitler's answer is correct. You will not bubble to the application controller, but you will bubble to the application route. However if you need the same action to be triggered wherever the component is utilized, than why dont you just have the action in the component itself?

Comment: Either way the action will reach the application route, unless another route handles the action and doesn't return true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actions don't bubble up through controllers, when an action is triggered it will go through the current route's controller, if nothing handles it there it bubbles up to the current route all the way up to the top level route (application).

If that action has to set a property on the controller you can set it directly from the application route (although it is not recommended).

```
// routes/application.js
actions {
  addAlert(message) {
      this.controller.set('message', message);
    },
    removeAlert(message) {
      this.controller.set('message', message);
    }
}
```

For more information read up on [action bubbling](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/templates/actions/#toc_action-bubbling).

Comment: That was exactly my problem, thank you. Why do actions bubble up in routes, but not controllers? Any specific reason?

Comment: Honestly, I never asked that question x.x I ll update you when I find out why

Comment: Please do! I am curious about that

Comment: I can't get anything bubbling up to the Route level. Did everything on the guides. Are you guys using Ember 1.13?

Comment: @BrenoInojosa post a new question with details of how you are doing it